# SSIS OLEDB - Receiving error ORA-01403 No Data Found when trying to load records into oracle GTT

Tags: sql, oracle, ssis, oledb

I am trying to load records from one table, on a SQL Server, into a global temp table on a Oracle server. I'm able to load the records successfully if I set the dataflow task to a default table name, but it runs far to slow for what I need. It's when I set it to a FAST load, that I run into this error message. I am using the Native OLE DB\Oracle Provider for Oracle. Initially, I thought it was an issue with the oracle provider, but whenever I try this on a different table (permanent), on a different server, it runs fine. I tried switching with Microsoft's oracle provider, but that threw a different error message entirely.

Would there be a setting on the GTT that would block fast loads, or would it be something else entirely? I did not create the GTT. Here's the error output:

```
[GTT_Variable [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.

An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "OraOLEDB"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "ORA-01403: no data found".

[Facets GTT [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.
The "GTT_Variable.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "GTT_Variable.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. 
An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  
The ProcessInput method on component "GTT_Variable" (2) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (15). 
The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. 
The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  
There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
```

Thanks

Comment: Oracle's handling of Global Temporary Tables is weird and unlike most other databases.  Perhaps the global temporary table is set to only last for the duration of the transaction, instead of the session, and SSIS is executing a commit and removing the data?  Check the duration of the table with this query: `select duration, all_tables.* from all_tables where table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME';`  If it's set to TRANSACTION, maybe recreating the table as SESSION would help.

Comment: I just checked. The duration is set to session.